# Editing a column to equal its first value

Tags: python, pandas

I have some inconsistencies with some data that I would like to fix

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy 
import io  


datastring = """
ride_id,start_time,end_time,driver_id,region,is_completed
4,5,2021-01-15 21:02:58,NaN,2,Cape Town,1
26,27,2021-03-31 21:51:00,NaN,2,San Francisco,1
0,1,2021-04-07 10:31:41,NaN,4,San Francisco,1
23,24,2021-02-20 06:37:07,NaN,4,San Francisco,1
7,8,2021-02-14 00:39:40,NaN,6,San Francisco,0
10,11,2021-02-15 11:23:45,NaN,6,San Francisco,1
3,4,2021-04-22 01:22:34,NaN,7,Paris,0
24,25,2021-02-19 13:01:37,NaN,7,Busan,1
19,20,2021-01-16 03:24:06,NaN,7,San Deigo,1
22,23,2021-03-02 04:07:27,NaN,13,San Francisco,1
28,29,2021-03-21 08:33:48,NaN,13,Los Angeles,1
8,9,2021-03-25 22:14:04,NaN,13,San Francisco,1
6,7,2021-02-22 15:31:42,NaN,13,Boston,1
"""

data = io.StringIO(datastring)
dddd = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",").reset_index()


dddd
```

I would like for the driver's region to be set to the first observation, so for example driver 2's second observation would mark his region as Cape Town, not San Francisco.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `groupby` will group observations by `driver_id`. Use of `transform` will let you set every row in a group to the first row value.

```
dddd['region'] = dddd.groupby('driver_id')['region'].transform('first')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
dddd = dddd.merge(dddd.groupby('driver_id').region.first().to_frame().reset_index(), on='driver_id', how='right').drop('region_x', axis=1).rename(columns={'region_y':'region'})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted something scalable, try pyspark;

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df=spark.createDataFrame(dddd)

win=Window.partitionBy("driver_id")

df.withColumn('region', f.first('region').over(win)).show()

+-----+-------+-------------------+--------+---------+-------------+------------+
|index|ride_id|         start_time|end_time|driver_id|       region|is_completed|
+-----+-------+-------------------+--------+---------+-------------+------------+
|    4|      5|2021-01-15 21:02:58|    null|        2|    Cape Town|           1|
|   26|     27|2021-03-31 21:51:00|    null|        2|    Cape Town|           1|
|    0|      1|2021-04-07 10:31:41|    null|        4|San Francisco|           1|
|   23|     24|2021-02-20 06:37:07|    null|        4|San Francisco|           1|
|    7|      8|2021-02-14 00:39:40|    null|        6|San Francisco|           0|
|   10|     11|2021-02-15 11:23:45|    null|        6|San Francisco|           1|
|    3|      4|2021-04-22 01:22:34|    null|        7|        Paris|           0|
|   24|     25|2021-02-19 13:01:37|    null|        7|        Paris|           1|
|   19|     20|2021-01-16 03:24:06|    null|        7|        Paris|           1|
|   22|     23|2021-03-02 04:07:27|    null|       13|San Francisco|           1|
|   28|     29|2021-03-21 08:33:48|    null|       13|San Francisco|           1|
|    8|      9|2021-03-25 22:14:04|    null|       13|San Francisco|           1|
|    6|      7|2021-02-22 15:31:42|    null|       13|San Francisco|           1|
+-----+-------+-------------------+--------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways one that's easiest is

```
for driver_id in dddd.driver_id.unique():
    dddd[dddd['driver_id']==driver_id]= dddd[dddd['driver_id']==driver_id].iloc[0]
dddd
```

Please comment if you need more clarification